# I Want to replace yes/no option with check or crossmark dynamically in php

Tags: php, mysql, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a MySQL table column with enum data type "1","0" (Yes,No). On runtime I want to change the yes option with checkmark and No option with crossmark. I am using bootstrap glyphicon. So far I have done the following :

```
<?php
if ($row_healthplans['PlatinumPlan']=1) {
    echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-center"></span>';
} else {
    echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
}
?>
```

I don't know what's wrong but it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its not

```
    if ($row_healthplans['PlatinumPlan']=1)
```

its ==

```
    if ($row_healthplans['PlatinumPlan']==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 0 is false and anything else is true in php, you could simply do:

```
if(!$row_healthplans['PlatinumPlans']){
    ... code for dash
}
else{
    ... code for plus
}
```

You might even consider ternary operation for this:

```
$symbol = ($row_healthplans['PlatinumPlan']) ? ... plus glyph icon : ... minus glyph icon;
```

That is, only if the end result will be a variable with the correct glyph icon is desired and other processing isn't needed.

I hope this helps.